# How can I get redis workers to access these sets in a non-blocking way to the inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, lua, redis

I want to have the following workflow set up:

Request sets below which acts as a lock

```
SET locks lock_value NX PX 5000
```

If that returns 0, the request stops. If it returns 1 it does

```
INCR lock_value
INCR global_count
```

So I have 1 set, global_count and I can have many sets lock_value as that's a variable. Then I release my lock with this LUA script:

```
if redis.call("get",KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then
    return redis.call("del",KEYS[1])
else
    return 0
end
```

I will be processing these actions constantly.

However, every 5 minutes I want to loop through all of the existing different lock_values of which there is a large number and insert each of the lock_values into a database. This won't be as fast as ordinary redis operations. How do I do this looping part separate from the lock/insert data/drop lock part. Should it be in a separate process?

I think I want two processes or two redis servers. One to set the lock, increment data, drop lock over and over. The other to periodically scan the lock_values and dump it into the database, without being blocked by the LUA script. For each lock_value, it's not crucial if some values aren't completely up-to-date with the first loop, so long as the next loop 5 minute later picks up any increments that are missed.

Is this possible?